# Regex to use in HTML source

Tags: regex

I need a regex to extract the number **330** on `...163&angleKreludor=330&viewID=...`. This number vary from day to day...it could be an Integer with up to 3 digits, but it can be a double number like 127.57 with 2 decimal places ... so I would need to capture anything between **angleKreludor=** and **&viewID...**. Here is the complete HTML:

```
var swf = new SWFObject('http://images.lulaser.com/shenkuu/lunar/shenkuu_calendar_v1.swf?angleNeopia=163&angleKreludor=330&viewID=2&lang=pt', 'flash_36175654223', '550', '500', '6', '#FFFFFF');
swf.addParam('quality', 'high');
swf.addParam('scale', 'exactfit');
swf.addParam('menu', 'false');
swf.addParam('allowScriptAccess', 'always');
swf.addParam('swLiveConnect', 'true');
swf.addParam('bgcolor', 'white');
swf.write();
```

P.S: This is needed to use in Javascript code in Selenium IDE ... I tried in the past and Selenium IDE does not accept look-aheads nor look-behinds

Comment: Your question doesn't actually contain a single line of HTML. You have what looks like JavaScript (although it might be ActionScript), and what you're trying to parse is URL-encoded data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for digits with positive look-behind for the `angleKreludor=` key

```
(?<=angleKreludor=)(\d+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/r6Yguf/1)

For JavaScript use non-captuinrg group

```
(?:angleKreludor=)(\d+)
```

```js
var s = 'http://images.lulaser.com/shenkuu/lunar/shenkuu_calendar_v1.swf?angleNeopia=163&angleKreludor=330&viewID=2&lang=pt';
var nr = s.match(/(?:angleKreludor=)(\d+)/);
console.log(nr[1]);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/r6Yguf/2)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I forgot to mention, I'm using Selenium IDE and its javascript command doest not work with look-aheads and look-behind ... I used the command: javascript{storedVars[“search”].search(/(?<=angleKreludor=)(\\d+)/);} and it returned "[error] Unexpected Exception: SyntaxError: illegal character. " -- I updated the question